# UITableViewCell custom, update UILabel

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have custom UITableView and UIImageView, UILabel in it. On some notification I need to update only UILabel not UIImageView. If I do like this:

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idxCell inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

All content of the cell is updating and I have flicker effect for UIImageView.
I've done like this:

```
MyTableViewCell *cell = (MyTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:0]];
cell.counterLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", counter];
```

But I think that it is not good, because it is not corresponds to the MVC pattern. I guess I should update my Model object. I need advice, How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should update your NSArray or NSDictionary from where u fetch data. because when u reload row it again call the same dictionary or array and that has same value.

didSelectRowAtIndexPath at update the dictionary or array 
and then reload the row.

cellForRowAtIndexPath update that NSArray or NSDictionary which fetch data for row.

May be it works